# Remove Matching List(of Object) from Another List(of Object) using LINQ

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I am having a bit of a difficult time figuring out how accomplish a task outlined in my question header.

Basically, I have a list of '`News`' objects defined as:

```
Dim news_list As List(Of News) = myNamespcae.News.ListNews()
```

Depending on a condition, I have another 'News' object list as;

```
Dim news_headlines As List(Of News) = myNamespace.News.getHeadlines()
```

Then, I have 'spots' again as List(of News) as;

```
Dim spots = (From n In news_list Take (10) Select n)
```

I am trying to accomplish;
if news_headlines is not empty,if any news_headlines News object exists in spots, remove it from spots. return filtered spots.

Any guidance will be appreciated..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick ten from `Spots` and then filter out the ones in `news_headlines`, it would be something like this (warning: LINQ syntax in VB entirely from memory):

```
Dim spots1 = (From n In news_list Take (10) Select n)
Dim spots2 = (From n in spots1 Where Not news_headlines.Contains(n) Select n)
```

If you want to filter out the ones in `news_headlines` and then pick ten, it would be something like this:

```
Dim spots1 = (From n In news_list Where Not news_headlines.Contains(n) Select n)
Dim spots2 = (From n in spots1 Take (10) select n)
```

You can of course combine the two queries.  Note that I'm assuming `news_headlines` is not null.  I'm also assuming that your news items are either the same object instances or implement `IEquatable<T>`.

Comment: Thank you Ann, I want to get rid of all news_headlines and remove them from news_list

Comment: @Emin  So you want to change the contents of `news_list`?  Or just exclude the contents of `news_headlines` from the ones that end up in `spots`?

Comment: Ok it seems like I caused a confusion. Basically, both news_list and news_headlines are List(of MyNewsObject) so they are identical in type. What I want is to create another list that would hold all the items from news_list excluding the ones in news_headlines... So think of spots as;
spots = news_list - news_headlines

Comment: I think my second code snippet should do what you want (when corrected for syntax as necessary!)

Comment: L I couldn't get your code working. This is how I got it working:  Dim ids = New HashSet(Of Integer)(news_headlines.Select(Function(x) x.NewsID))
                If ids.Count > 0 Then
                    spots = news_list.Where(Function(x) Not ids.Contains(x.NewsID)).Take(10)
                End If 
But I can't understand why your code did not give me the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are similar questions in stackoverflow. Anyway, you can possibly use ["Intersect"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) to get the elements that are both in the spots and the headlines and remove them from the spots list.

The code should be trivial but I haven't used VB.net in a while, sorry.